# Twitter bootstrap data-src in card not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Going by the [example](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) given on twitter bootstrap's website, the following code

```
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100%x180/" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

should produce a nice card, but it produces

[image]

Can anyone tell what the problem could be?
Seems like the data attributes are not working for me.

Comment: What are you tring to achieve with this? Show an image, or a static generated image (as holder.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @bsmp is right in his answer.

Holder will then process all images with a specific src attribute, like `src="holder.js/318x180"`, and generates an image source in to `data-src` attribute automatically.

1. Include holder in your page by using the following code:

   `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/holder/2.9.0/holder.min.js">
   </script>`

   You can also download holder.js at https://github.com/imsky/holder
2. Use the `src` attribute of the `img` element to define your holder images:

   `<img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/318x180" alt="Card image cap">
   <div class="card-block">`

Notice that you do not have to escape the holder syntax in the `src` attribte for the latest version of holder.js

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card" style="width:318px;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/318x180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
<h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/holder/2.9.0/holder.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The example you grabbed the code from is using holder.js but the Bootstrap distribution does not actually come with holder.js. Your data-src attribute is referencing a file that doesn't exist.

If you need a placeholder image you can:

- [Get Holder.js](http://holderjs.com/)
- Use a different placeholder service like [Placehold.it](https://placehold.it/) or [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com/)

If you use a regular image, remember that you have to use the normal source attribute:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap">
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to holder.js. I updated the question. The issue arises even with placehold.it

Comment: @PratikKhadloya - You need to use the `src` attribute for regular images. Note that Placehold.it's example image looks like this: `<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">`. I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya - I also just reverted that edit you made; people with the same issue need to see the original problem. Don't update the question with suggestions from answers.